# Windows 8 GridView - disabling item tap visualization

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to remove the tap effect on an item inside a gridview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you need to modify the GridViewItem style in the ItemContainerStyle property.

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderBrush}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <TapDownThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDisabledOpacity}" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionHintStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition To="NoSelectionHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="VerticalSelectionHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToVerticalOffset="25" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToVerticalOffset="25" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToVerticalOffset="25" ToHorizontalOffset="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="HorizontalSelectionHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectionBackground" ToHorizontalOffset="-25" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentBorder" ToHorizontalOffset="-25" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                            <SwipeHintThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" ToHorizontalOffset="-25" ToVerticalOffset="0" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoSelectionHint" />
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selecting">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectingGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselecting">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="HintGlyphBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition To="NotDragging" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.650" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragOpacity}" />
                                            <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent" />
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="OuterContainer" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <!-- These two Opacity animations are required - the FadeInThemeAnimations
                                        on the same elements animate an internal Opacity. -->
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="InnerDragContent" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragOpacity}" />
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" />
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="MultiArrangeOverlayText" />
                                            <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="InnerDragContent" />
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" />
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="SelectedBorder" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ContentContainer" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition To="NoReorderHint" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.65" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintOffset}" Direction="Bottom" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintOffset}" Direction="Top" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintOffset}" Direction="Right" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DragOverThemeAnimation TargetName="ReorderHintContent" ToOffset="{StaticResource ListViewItemReorderHintOffset}" Direction="Left" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                                <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlightBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                                    <!-- This extra wrapper grid is necessary because rendertransforms set by the reorder hint animations
                                will be lost when ContentContainer becomes a LTE -->
                                    <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                        <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0" Margin="4">
                                            <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckHintGlyphBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPointerOverBrush}" Margin="1" />
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemKeyboardFocusBrush}" />
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground" Margin="4" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlightBrush}" Opacity="0" />
                                        <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="4">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                                <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                                            In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                                            approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
                                                <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" Visibility="Collapsed" Text="Xg" Foreground="{x:Null}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Visibility="Collapsed" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderRectBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stroke="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlightBrush}" StrokeThickness="{StaticResource GridViewItemSelectedBorderThickness}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter" IsHitTestVisible="False" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="4">
                                            <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Opacity="0" Height="40" Width="40">
                                                <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemHighlightBrush}" Stretch="Fill" />
                                                <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemCheckGlyphBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundBrush}" Margin="4" />
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Text="{Binding TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4">
                        <TextBlock.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="56" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light" />
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,0,0,0" />
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="WordEllipsis" />
                            </Style>
                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
</GridView>
```

Note that the default style of system controls changes between versions of the OS. The Windows 10 expanded (note that the platform renders the items with simplified visual tree by default to improve performance) style of the `GridViewItem` can be found in `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\themeresources.xaml"` (or some such place in the themeresources.xaml file) by searching for `TargetType="GridViewItem"`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please provide me a sample? thanks.

Comment: I resolved in this way:<GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>

Comment: Oh, which tap effect did you mean? Modifying GridViewItem style would allow you to remove the highlight. Setting IsHitTestVisible to false on the panel probably disables all clicks etc. and lets them bubble to the parent UIElement.

Comment: I want to remove the "pressed" effect when you tap an item..Actually IsHitTestVisible disables all click, and it's not what I want. Any  thoughts?

Comment: You can change SelectionMode to None or you can change the template as I mentioned originally.

Comment: The SelectionMode is already "none". Could you provide me a sample template?

Comment: Added an extracted template. I think that should work - just need to edit the template - maybe comment out the VisualState transitions with "<!-- -->". Somehow extracting the ItemContainerStyle does not work for me in the VS designer in GridView, but you can simply put a GridViewItem in your XAML and then you can extract its ControlTemplate - that's what I had done.

Comment: Really thanks for posting the Style here imposbile to find in the MSDN

Comment: Note though that the default style might have and most likely did change in WIndows 10 since Windows 8/8.1.

Comment: The Windows 10 style is here on my machine: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\themeresources.xaml"

Answer (score 6):

IsHitTestVisible="False" will be the fastest solution when just a read-only grid view is needed.

Answer (score 5):

This is perfect solution on W8.1

```
 <Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
<Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing storyboard of visualstate "PointerOver" and "PointerOverPressed" in "GridViewItemStyle" will disable pointer hover and pressed animations.

sample source code: http://files.cnblogs.com/Tealcwu/ItemContainerStyleSelectorDemo.zip

please refer to http://www.cnblogs.com/Tealcwu/archive/2012/11/07/2759132.html, the last section.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.