# GridView selection color in WinRT Metro

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How do I set / change the item selection color in XAML for a WinRT GridView control? I've tried looking around, is there also a procedure for doing it visually on Blend for VS11?

I've looked at GridView.ItemContainerStyle tag and I couldn't find much help online.

Answer (score 0):

There was an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359197/windows-8-gridview-disabling-item-tap-visualization) that was asked about disabling tap visualization in a GridView that might help you.
Extracting the style of a GridViewItem is not available on the GridView itself, so if you want to do it yourself - you need to put a GridViewItem control separately in some page/user control and use the designer tool to edit the template. Or you can just use mine from that other question. I think what you would need to change is the use of the ListViewItemHighlightBrush in that template.

Comment: <TapDownThemeAnimation> was not supported in Metro. could not proceed.

Comment: What build of Windows 8 do you have? This is code taken from the Consumer Preview build and it does work there. If you are on Developer Preview or any non-public build - you are on your own. :)