# WinRT: how can I set diffrent pointer over effect for elements in gridview?

Tags: winrt-xaml

I need to set different rollover effect for elements in gridview. I created calendar and need to back-light days that were gone and remove rollover effect for other days.
How can I do this?

I found similar question
[Windows 8 GridView - disabling item tap visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359197/windows-8-gridview-disabling-item-tap-visualization)
but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The roll-over effects for a GridView are managed as part of its ItemContainerStyle.

In Visual Studio, right-click on the GridView on the left and select Edit Additional Templates, Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle), Edit a Copy.

In the style that gets generated you'll find a VisualStateGroup called "Hover". These are the changes that take place to the container when a user is hovering over an item.  At the bottom of the template you'll find the item container and the default wrapper for the grid-item (a border with checkbox).  You'll need to change this and then modify the VisualStateGroups as appropriate.